# jQuery unload vs beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why would you ever want to use `$(window).unload(function(){});` over `$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){});`

And is there a difference between binding the beforeunload using jQuery like above, and assigning it directly like this: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { };`

Comment: This is already answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376596/jquery-unload-or-beforeunload]

Answer (score 1):

Also read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_events.html#link5

jQuery will always try to use addEventListener before using the 'direct' way (and attachEvent). addEventlistener can cancel bubbling and can attach multiple callbacks.