# OnBeforeUnload ajax request not working on IE8 a IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have been searching alot for a solution to be able to be able to send an ajax request when the user closes the browser.So far all I have found is the onBeforeUnload event.This is what I have so far:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: '/Home/Get/'
  });
});
```

and I have also tryed using the native javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: '/Home/Get/'
    });
};
```

Now my interesest is not to recieve back the callback I only want to be able to execute a method on the server side when the browser closes.

This seems to work reliable on chrome , firefox  an IE10 , but it does not work on IE9 and IE8 at all.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Try it with `.on()` instead of `.bind()`; see if that works!!.

Comment: the application uses jQuery 1.5 and this has nothing to do with jQuery I have also tryed using window.onBeforeUnload and te same problem exist

Comment: Please check if [this](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onbeforeunload.htm) is working on your browser

Comment: whenI try to display the pop up box it works fine on IE9 and IE8 but I do not want to display it I want to send the call to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a synchronous request to do that.
Browsers may not wait an asynchronous request complete(or even established.)
here is another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376596/jquery-unload-or-beforeunload), please refer to it.

but there is one thing you should care about is: **when using synchronous ajax call, user's browser will be blocked until the ajax call complete.** It's not good for the user experience. And even worse, if your some bug happened in your server and the ajax request can not complete, the browser will be **not responding**. so be careful to do this!

BTW, for a good design, the server should not rely on the ajax request sent by the client to do some clean-up job. If you have to do such a job, use some other techniques, such as implementing a `heartbeat` mechanism.