# back button not firing onbeforeunload event with iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a wizard form (single html page with multiple form sections) that I am validating using multiple Ajax calls (POST requests to and from an iFrame for IE9 support) and I am having some very strange behavior with an onbeforeunload() event.  On 2/3 sections of the form I want this event to occur, it does, but one particular form segment has strange behavior when I click the browser back button.

Here is how I administer the property:

```
$(window).on({
    beforeunload : function(e) {
    return "If you navigate away from the page, you'll lose any unsaved information.";}
});
```

When I click on the browser back button in the particular spot in the page, my ajax call fires and the success callback activates.  Super crazy.  I've tried setting that property everywhere I can think of.  Any advice is appreciate.  I can paste more relevant code if need be.

EDIT:  Also, through some form of sorcery, the title of the page changes in the broswer tab to the page's URL, strange...

Comment: Is your page set up with any `#` style anchor tags or single-page-app-like navigation? Hitting back might be re-routing the app and causing the ajax to fetch.

Comment: This might help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376596/jquery-unload-or-beforeunload 

try using window.onbeforeunload = function() { /* do stuff */ };

Comment: I don't believe we have any anchor tags with # as the href.

Comment: I gave that a run, @zfrisch, and it didn't seem to get the job done.  Thank you, however.

Comment: Not enough code shown to replicate your issue