# window.onbeforeunload works when close tab, but doesn't work when close browser

Tags: javascript, jsf, firefox, primefaces, onbeforeunload

Sorry mi english.

I'm using Firefox 38, JSF 2.0, Primefaces 4 and Primefaces Extensions 1.2,  in Chrome works perfectly

my code is

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ rcCloseWindow(); };
```

I need to call a managed bean method ONLY when browser is closed

```
<pe:remoteCommand name="rcCloseWindow" actionListener="#{loginManagedBean.whatever}" async="true"/>
```

This works in firefox when i close tab, but not when i close browser, in Chrome works perfectly

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a normal js function instead of a `pe:remoteCommand`? Just to see it being called?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376596/jquery-unload-or-beforeunload