# Angular 4: Identify browser/tab close event and page refresh event

Tags: angular

I went to this link [How can I handle browser tab close event in Angular? Only close, not refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129319/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close-event-in-angular-only-close-not-refresh)

But I don't know how to achieve this in Angular 4.

I am not able to identify when page is refreshed and when tab or browser is closed.

Because in both cases it fires "window:unload" and window:beforeunload" event so it's hard to identify.

Actually I want to fire logout event when browser or tab is closed but it fire in case of refresh as well.

Following is my code.

```
  @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    this.recordLogOut();
  }
```

Any input/direction/help would be appreciated.

Comment: This SO post may or may not be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

[Unload or beforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376596/jquery-unload-or-beforeunload)

Use beforeunload. For your case it should be enough, where you will send a request.

In my case where i need to popup custom dialog, confirmation does not block refresh/close tab event. (`return false` leave me with the default dialog)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I tried with beforeunload and It's create problem when some one do a page refresh. It's getting called when do page refresh and not able to identify between refresh and tab/screen close.

Comment: That is because you can not override or hook this kinds of events in the browser any more. You can try key pressed or on press evens but that only work for keyboard shortcuts. I could not find a solution for pressing refresh or close tab. You can try to store the url and on loading if it the same or not to do proper action(if i remember correctly Router.url).

Comment: Thanks @Teodor Still I didn't get any solution for this issue. Will try what you suggested.

Comment: No. It's not working properly because event fire each time when you do a refresh.

Comment: You can check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129319/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close-event-in-angular-only-close-not-refresh?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I think refresh is unload by itself. Not sure but you may need session storage for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage. Just check for credential/flag and if there is non just redirect to login and then store a flag or credentials there. For your case I think it is enough. Sorry for the late reply.